# stop the scroll of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in front end. I need to control the scrolling of an image until the scrolling of the images on the right side ends up, adding the class isLocked to 
stop scrolling the image on the left side while the banners on the right side are rolling and add the class isAtBottom when the scroll of the images on the right side ends. Thanks!!

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/silvio7d/avgdcLq6/63/

JS

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){    
  var element = document.getElementById('main-feature');
  if (element.scrollHeight + element.scrollTop == element.scrollHeight){           
    element.classList.add('isLocked');
    element.classList.remove('isAtBottom');
  } else {
    element.classList.add('isAtBottom'); 
    element.classList.remove('isLocked');
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.main-banner.isLocked {
        position: fixed;
    }

    .main-banner.isAtBottom {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Comment: "When the image is at end" - end of what? BTW: `element.scrollHeight + element.scrollTop == element.scrollHeight` is the same as `element.scrollTop == 0`, but that doesn't solve your problem, just a note

Comment: I updated the description of the issue . Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a parallax effect?

Comment: I don't think it's exactily a parallax effect.

Comment: I'd like to use Vanilla Js instead of react that was used in the site above

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve this behavior using CSS only with `position: sticky` so long as you're only supporting [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

```
.main-banner {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0
}
```

See this [example](https://codepen.io/brianhadaway/pen/qQeMjQ).

Comment: Hi, Brian. This solution is very interesting the only problem is the supporting.May be using vendor prefixed solves the problem

Comment: You're correct. I've added the `-webkit-sticky` value to the answer above. The code in the linked example uses autoprefixer so the compiled code contains prefixed css props as needed.

Comment: Is there any solution using pure JS?